# Rate of Convergence for a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, recurrence-relations

Hi I am trying to do a question on rate of convergence

I have come across the definition

If a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to a value $r$ and if there exist real numbers $\beta > 0$ and $\alpha \geq 1$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|x_{n+1} - r|}{|x_n - r|} $$

then $\alpha$ is the rate of convergence.

I am trying to obtain alpha for the following question or rather obtain alpha using the above expression.

$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{6^n-4}$$

Therefore from the given expression i know i need to obtain $a_{n+1}$
where

$$a_{n+1} = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{6^{n+1}-4}$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{6^{n+1}-4} |}{|\frac{(-1)^n}{6^n-4}|}= $$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{6^n-4}{6^{n+1}-4} = \frac{1}{6} $$

Evaluating the above limit gives $\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: Where have you seen this definition for ratio of convergence? Could you write down the link?

Comment: http://www.math-cs.gordon.edu/courses/ma342/handouts/rate.pdf i was reading this @Jaca

Comment: $(-1)^n/(6^n-4)$ isn't the same as $(-1/6)^n$, so you certainly can't do what you propose to do. Also, to use the definition you give, you need to know $r$, the limit of the sequence – do you know what $r$ is for your sequence?

Comment: no r was given to me just the sequence as shown in the question I was using the definition to try and evaluate so what was given to me was just a sequence @GerryMyerson

Comment: The definition has an $r$ in it, which means you can't use the definition unless you know the value of $r$, which means your first job is to figure out the value of $r$. Can you do that? Can you find what $a_n$ converges to?

Comment: Yes @GerryMyerson r is 0

Comment: Good. Now, stick that into the definition. What do you get?

Comment: yeah i updated the question i sicked it into the definition @ Gerry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104953/discussion-between-amir-and-gerry-myerson).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat. There was an $\alpha$ in your next-to-last equation, then it was gone in your last equation. How did that happen?

Comment: yes @GerryMyerson after doing some more research I saw that you can use the following to evaluate the rate of convrgence $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|x_{n+1} - r|}{|x_n - r|}$$ and so I updated the expression and hence the $\alpha$ was no longer in the expression

Comment: But now the question makes no sense. "If there exist real numbers $\beta$ and $\alpha$ such that..." and then there's a limit but no indication of what property that limit should have nor how it should relate to $\beta$ and $\alpha$.